# Odd console.memory results in Chrome, negative numbers in timeline memory dev tools, a Chrome bug?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, google-chrome-devtools

After running for a very long time (a day or more) a web-based app I wrote (JS/HTML5) starts acting "weird".  Primarily it stops sending the normal data it should to the backend, where I expect it to be sending ~500kb of data it starts sending just a few bytes of nonsense.  I suspected this was memory related (unable to allocate memory or something?) and when I investigated I saw something truly strange and seemingly impossible, which suggests to me that it's a Chrome bug I'm encountering perhaps through high memory usage.  But I could use some confirmation from someone who knows better than I do.

The main oddness seems to be what [console.memory](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/timing/properties/memory) spits out.  The linked document says that "usedJsHeapSize can not be greater than totalJsHeapSize" which it very, very much is.  It's also higher than the heap size limit, which I imagine it should not be:

[image: Results of console.memory call]

I then tried to see what devtools might tell me and did a timeline of memory at that instant, for a few seconds, and look at what it says....  the memory ranges from some negative insanely big number to 0B.  That sure doesn't seem right.

[image: Timeline of memory usage]

And I checked the chrome://memory report and while it is using a lot of memory, comparing that to other Chrome browsing sessions I have going it doesn't seem freakish.

[image: chrome://memory]

Can anyone confirm this is a Chrome bug versus expected dev tools behavior I'm not interpreting correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: You're saying, "I have this thing that is odd to me.  I am going to keep it secret from you.  Now, is it odd?"  "Only that what it is a secret," is my reply.  BTW: My heartbeat averages 57bpm which is lower than most.  Can you confirm if that is weird?  If it is not, please explain.  Sorry, I am being unfair... you don't know my medical status.

Comment: Ummm...  That's certainly not what I was intending to do, nor what I think I did.  I just thought a) it's not likely that anyone who wants to help me wants to sign up for and run my software for 24+ hours to see it exhibit this behavior, b) my question doesn't require that, because I just want to know if these memory numbers make any sense at all (are valid/legal/possible) or is their very existence proof that there is a Chrome bug I'm likely triggering.

Comment: If you exceed a maximum number, you'll get negative numbers.  If your script isn't managing objects stored effeciently, then it will continue to grow.  Is it normal?  Well, if that's how your script is written, yeppers.  Without seeing the code, there's no way to know what's going on.  You ran it for 24hrs, but the script can most likely be sped up to execute routines much faster and replicate the issue, helping to identify the cause.  What we have now is a description of the symptoms of a problem without being able to analyze it... hence a mystery novel.

Answer (score 3):

- Values are bucketed to prevent side-channel attacks
- Bucketing described here: http://goo.gl/fFspKO
- Get precise numbers with Chrome flag: --enable-precise-memory-info